# How to pass dynamic data to email template desgined on sendgrid webapp ? :-| Sendgrid

Tags: email, html-email, sendgrid

I integrated sendgrid email service with my sample application.
& also able to send email to user.

But **how to pass dynamic data to Email template design on sendGrid webapp?** 
is there any way to send dynamic data to email template designed on sendgrid?

for ex. I designed Welcome email template on sendgrid. & I want to pass
dynamic data to this template i.e UserName , emailId, City etc.. using java
code ?
when  any user registered with my application then I want to send welcome
email to that user. with information of user like UserName , emailId, City
etc.. through our database.

What to do ? How to do ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of focusing on substitution via the Email Template application (which is not possible), You should take a look at the [SMTPAPI](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=smtp_api). By adding a X-SMTPAPI header in your message, you can

1. Control the settings of your SendGrid account (i.e. [change filter settings on the fly](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=filters))
2. Send to up to 1000 recipient addresses in a single SMTP transaction ([SMTPAPI To: Array](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=smtp_api_dev))
3. Perform mail-merge like substitutions in the mail body ([SMTPAPI Sub: Associative Array](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=smtp_api_dev))

Finally this is assuming you are sending email directly via our SMTP or Web API. If you are using our newsletter feature, mail-merge like substitution is possible by using [Custom Tags](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=newsletter:custom_fields) in the newsletter template.

-- Joe

SendGrid

Comment: Is it possible to combine substitution tags and Template Engine?

Comment: Check out my comment here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883246/adding-array-data-to-sendgrid-templates/33602379#33602379

Comment: Links are broken in this answer - I found [this article](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html) helpful in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think [it is possible now](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USAGE.md#mail_settings), by adding a `substitutions` key in the options. I also added the `to` key because that one is mandatory.

```
$request_body = json_decode('{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "substitutions": {
        "-first_name-": "John",
        "-last_name-": "Doe"
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "john.doe@example.com",
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}');
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->body();
print_r($response->headers());
```

Template in Sendgrid looks like this:

```
Dear -first_name- -last_name-,

Foo bar...

Kind Regards
```

Comment: Substitutions object keys should not contain substitution warper characters i.e. "-first_name-" -> "first_name".