# How to pass dynamic data to email template of sendgrid?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I have integrated sendgrid in Laravel and I managed to send the email template of sendgrid in emails but I am not able to replace the content in the email templates. I am using Sendgrid Web API V3.

I followed the steps given in the below link but it is not replacing the variables in template with my dynamic data.

Link: [How to pass dynamic data to email template desgined on sendgrid webapp ? :-| Sendgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014393/how-to-pass-dynamic-data-to-email-template-desgined-on-sendgrid-webapp-sen)

Here is code

```
$sg = new \SendGrid('API_KEY');           
$request_body = json_decode('{
            "personalizations":[
               {
                  "to":[
                     {
                        "email":"example@example.com"
                     }
                  ],
                  "subject":"Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!"

               }
            ],
            "from":{
               "email":"from@example.com"
            },
            "content":[
               {
                  "type":"text/html",
                  "value":"<html><body> -name- </body></html>"
               }
            ],
            "sub": {
                "-name-": ["Alice"]
              },
            "template_id":"xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx"

        }');

$mailresponse = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
echo $mailresponse->statusCode();
echo $mailresponse->body();
echo $mailresponse->headers();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have overcome this issue by using another way. Below is code that is working fine. May be help some one..

```
//create mail object
 $mail = new \SendGrid\Mail();
//set from 
 $from = new \SendGrid\Email("SENDER NAME", "SENDER EMAIL");
 $mail->setFrom($from);
//set personalization
 $personalization = new \SendGrid\Personalization();
 $to = new \SendGrid\Email("RECEIVER NAME", "RECEIVER EMAIL");
 $personalization->addTo($to);
 $personalization->setSubject("SUBJECT");
//add substitutions (Dynamic value to be change in template)
 $personalization->addSubstitution(':name', "Any"); 

 $mail->addPersonalization($personalization);
 $mail->setTemplateId("TEMPLATE_ID");
//send email
 $sg = new \SendGrid("API_KEY");

 $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
```

Answer (score 5):

This works perfectly and is much simpler than the solutions already posted:

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom( "from@example.com", "Some guy" );
$email->addTo( "to@example.com", "Another guy" );
$email->setTemplateId(
    new \SendGrid\Mail\TemplateId( TEMPLATE_ID )
);

// === Here comes the dynamic template data! ===
$email->addDynamicTemplateDatas( [
    'variable1'     => 'Some stuff',
    'templatesRock' => 'They sure do!'
] );

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid( API_KEY );
$response = $sendgrid->send( $email );
```

Comment: What version are you using? $mail->addDynamicTemplateDatas does not exist on the v7 branch.

Comment: I was using ^7.0 as of one week ago, so it should be there! However I've now moved to Postmark and my life is infinitely better :P

Comment: I ended up calling their v3 API directly from the http client. The dynamic-template-args version is still unreleased in packagist (afaik). Seriously painful and their customer-service wasn't very helpful either.

I'd expect this from a free service. Not something we pay for every month.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but maybe this can help some one to. I faced the same problem and [@bwest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401096/bwest) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40386787) helped me to solve it:

The substitutions values cannot be an array and the should look [like](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html#-Sending-a-Single-Email-to-a-Single-Recipient):

```
`"personalizations":[{
       "to":[{
             "email":"example@example.com"
          }],
       "subject":"Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!",
       "substitutions": {
                "-name-": "Alice"
       }    
    }
    ],
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

IN JAVA use:

> ```
>     Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
> ```

and its methods for sending the dynamic data to sendgrid template and use {{}}
for receiving the data on sendgrid.